# How can i navigate forward and backward with out navigation controller

Tags: iphone, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

i am using UIViewcontroller in my application and i want to navigate forward when click on the button, and in 2nd view when i click back, the view is navigate back like navigation controller.How can i do this?I am not using navigation controller and i can't.Thanks

Comment: Why can't you use a UINavigationController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the second view as a subview of first one (with same size), to come back in to first view use the function removeFromSuperView from second view.

Answer (score 0):

use the following code
With navigation controller
push the controller

```
        DetailView *detailObj = [[DetailView alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView_Phone" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailObj animated:YES];
```

pop the controller

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

check out the [link](http://www.idev101.com/learn/navigation_controllers.html) for help
without navigation controller.

if you have a problem with navigation bar u can hide it also.

```
[self presentModalViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES];
```

using this u can move one view to another view

Regards,

Shyam